# Pandoc conversion from markdown to docx with blockquotes and citations

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

When I do this, I get a docx where my markdown blockquotes (>) have not been properly converted, but with citation conversion working:

`pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc --bibliography ref/my-refs.bib in.md -o out.docx -f markdown`

When I do this, the blockquotes work, but citations are not converted:

`pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc --bibliography ref/my-refs.bib in.md -o out.docx -f markdown_strict`

The only difference between the two is `markdown` vs `markdown_strict`

How can I get blockquotes + citations to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the [`blank_before_blockquote`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-blank_before_blockquote) extension:

> Extension: `blank_before_blockquote`
>
> Standard Markdown syntax does not require a blank line before a block
>   quote.  Pandoc does require this (except, of course, at the beginning of the
>   document). The reason for the requirement is that it is all too easy for a
>   `>` to end up at the beginning of a line by accident (perhaps through line
>   wrapping). So, unless the `markdown_strict` format is used, the following does
>   not produce a nested block quote in pandoc:
>
> ```
> > This is a block quote.
> >> Nested.
> ```

You can selectively disable this extension by using `-f markdown-blank_before_blockquote`.